# How to list closest user from current user location in a table view - iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, cllocationmanager

Here i am calculating user and driver lat long distance in km. Now i want list driver from user current in table view. Currently i can able to retrieve lat long from driver and user side and calculated distance between them.

here is the code used :

```
var requestArray     = [requestModel]()
var bookRequestArray = [String]()
var DriverArray      = [String]()
var subLoaclityArray = [String]()
var LocationArray    = [String]()

var doc_ID         : String = ""
var Start_Lat      : String = ""
var Start_Long     : String = ""
var Driver_Lat     : String = ""
var Driver_Long    : String = ""

var DriverLocation : CLLocation?
var userLocation   : CLLocation?
var nearestLoaction   : CLLocationDistance?
```

Here getting driver lat long for firestore in array

```
func loadDriverDoc(){

    self.db.collection("Driver_details").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("driverdocument::::::::::\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                self.DriverArray.append(document.documentID)
                let Driver_lat = document.data()["Driver_Lat"] as? String
                print("Driver_lat:::::\(String(describing: Driver_lat))")
                self.Driver_Lat = Driver_lat!
                let Driver_long = document.data()["Driver_Long"] as? String
                print("Driver_long:::::\(String(describing: Driver_long))")
                self.Driver_Long = Driver_long!

                self.DistanceCal()


            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {


            }


        }

    }


}
```

Here calculating distance between user and driver

```
func DistanceCal() {

     DriverLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double(Driver_Lat)!, longitude: Double(Driver_Long)!)
     userLocation   = CLLocation(latitude: Double(Start_Lat)!, longitude: Double(Start_Long)!)

    //this is the distance between driverLocation and startLocation (in km)
    let distance = (DriverLocation?.distance(from: userLocation!))!/1000

    //Display the result in km
    print(String(format: "The distance to driver is %.01fkm", distance))


    if (distance <= 1000) {



    } else if (distance <= 2000) {


    } else if (distance <= 3000) {


    } else {



    }

}//DistanceCal
```

here getting user data from firestore

```
func loadDoc() {

    getFireBaseToken { token in


            self.db.collection("Current_booking").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        print("document::::::::::\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                        self.bookRequestArray.append(document.documentID)
                        print("doc::::\(self.bookRequestArray)")
                        let Start_lat = document.data()["Start_Lat"] as? String
                        print("Start_lat::::::\(String(describing: Start_lat))")
                        self.Start_Lat = Start_lat!
                        let Start_long = document.data()["Start_Long"] as? String
                        print("Start_long::::::\(String(describing: Start_long))")
                        self.Start_Long = Start_long!

                         self.loadDriverDoc()
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.requestTableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            }


    }//get firebase token

}//loadDoc
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? To calculate all the distances between user and drivers? Or you can calculate those and you just need the sorting idea?

Comment: @DionizB calculate those and you just need the sorting idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would suggest creating a new object

```
struct Driver { 
   var docID: String!
   var location: CLLocation!
   var distanceFromUser: CLLocationDistance?
}
```

Also on top of class in variable declaration create an array of drivers:
`var drivers = [Driver]()`
You download all the drivers and init the structures of drivers, after that for every driver you calculate distance between to the current user and you assign to every driver `distanceFromUser`. After doing that you should sort

```
drivers.sort(by: {($0.distanceFromUser ?? 999999.9) < ($1.distanceFromUser ?? 999999.9)})
tableView.reloadData()
```

I gave 999999.9, since distanceFromUser is optional and if it isn't calculated that driver stays on bottom of the list. In  `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`   you should access `drivers[indexPath.row]` or `drivers[indexPath.section]` depending which way are you using the table view.